# Delete all files that it's name end with specific string

Tags: php

How to delete all files that it's name end with specific character

example of files that i want to delete

```
 /images/m/tme-500x500-3092.jpg
 /images/m/tme-200x200-3092.jpg
 /images/m/tme-300x400-3092.jpg
```

code

```
 $files = glob($basePath . '/../images/m/"*"3092.jpg');
 foreach ($files as $file) {
       unlink($file);
    }
```

what should i replace "*" with ?

Comment: Wouldn't just `glob($basePath . "/../images/m/tme-*-3092.jpg");` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you joking? :-)

Assuming that the path is right.

`$files = glob($basePath . '/../images/m/tme-*-3092.jpg');`

Comment: You're welcome :-). When this is the right answer - please mark it as the correct one or otherwise tell us what you're missing.